# Best ways to manage all the Data taken from Tables in a Database and stored in a WPF App

Tags: wpf, binding, viewmodel

Hi i am trying to find the best way to manage the Data (that comes from tables in a Database) in your App.

My main question is, what is the best approach to take to then i successfully work with Bindings, Notifying Properties/Collections Changes?

My App is to manage the Inventory of all kind of things in an Enterprise, so i collect the Data to my App, and then i am using DataViews to store it? But this is the best approch to then i can work with bindings and Notifying Changes?

I am recently entering in WPF (about 2 months), the concept of ViewModel it's what i am trying to understand now, because seems that is the most thing used to manage the Data stored in an WPF App. Or maybe i am understanding all wrong.

What I am asking is for advices and examples to then i understand which is the best aprroach.

Note: In my case i have a Main Window with a DataGrid which have DataGridTextColumns and DataGridComboBoxColumns, and i have auxiliary Windows to manage Categories, Places and etc with ListViews.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we are talking about WPF, then of-course we are talking about MVVM pattern, its the best way :)

This link is the best start point for MVVM pattern:

[MVVM for Beginners](http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/432/MVVM-for-Tarded-Folks-Like-Me-or-MVVM-and-What-it-Means-to-Me.aspx)

Comment: Ok but can you give good examples to do what i am talking about? Something that shows me how i can work and organize things to in my App i can store the contents that i got from my Tables in the Database. Something that gives me a good idea on how to do and how to do in the best way.